# Did President Franklin Roosevelt appear in Buck Rogers?

Tags: buck-rogers

Did Franklin Roosevelt appear in the Buck Rogers comic strip, as suggested in the quote below? If so, in what issue, or on which date?

From the [In Roosevelt History](http://fdrlibrary.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/found-in-the-archives-5/) blog:

> FDR: SPACE RANGER
>
> In March 1944, the publishers of the Buck Rogers in the 25th Century newspaper cartoon strip wrote to FDR asking permission to include a cartoon version of him in an upcoming strip. The proposed storyline had Buck Rogers exploring a new world and discovering a machine that could look back in time and compare good and evil. FDR, of course, was to be an example of humanity’s good, and Hitler and Japan’s Tojo were to be examples of evil. To sweeten the request, the publishers included a membership card making the President a member of the Buck Rogers Rocket Rangers! The White House gave permission for the proposed strip, but unfortunately we don’t know if it ever appeared.

[image: FDR's Rocket Rangers membership card]

Comment: The original comics are being republished, which would make it easier to find this out.  Unfortunately, volume 6 (http://www.amazon.com/Buck-Rogers-25th-Century-Newspaper/dp/1932563563/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1306994732&sr=1-5) was released yesterday June 1st, and only goes to 1938.  It's likely that there will be 3 more volumes before 1944 - perhaps 6-8 months away?

Comment: Volume 6 is now scheduled for release in February 2012.  So it looks like it will be a long time before 1944 is republished.

Comment: I wish I could answer this - I have the book:  "Collected Works of Buck Rogers in the 25th Century" -- The last comix in it are from 1943, and take place on Planet X inhabited by the Monkey Men (who devolved from Japanese soldiers who escaped after ww2)  The comic is deeply racist in depicting the monkey men, and I'd bet that this was leading to an FDR depiction.  My book does not have the FDR appearance however.

Comment: This question should be rephrased, "did he... and when", as there's no real indication it actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not much help, but I remember seeing a Buck Rogers strip reprinted years ago which depicted President Roosevelt as the president in the 25th century, and though it did not call him by name, the image was obviously a representation of Roosevelt. He was wearing a jumping belt or jet pack, and the interaction was brief, it was not part of a story line. I remember it because it was an anachronism. The strip never explained why the 25th Century president looked like Roosevelt, and as far as I know, it was a one-off. I don't remember which book I saw it in; it was a random reprint. Sorry for the lack of details, but this image does exist somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

There are no direct references to this comic on the internet, other than the blog post mentioned in the question.

Having said that, the comic in question could be "Monkeymen of Planet X", because it [features the Japanese](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicStrip/BuckRogers?from=Main.BuckRogers), of whom FDR is meant to contrast.  Also this comic was released during the time frame mentioned in the question and blog post.  The other mention of the Japanese probably occurred in a comic strip before the permission letter to FDR.

Comment: I don't see this as an especially helpful answer. The comic you're referencing is from 1943 whereas the letter to Roosevelt is from 1944; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?585565

Comment: The "Monkeymen of Planet X" story is published in The Collected Works of Buck Rogers in the 25th Century. FDR is not in that story. However, the next story in this collection is from 1946. Strips 134-151 are missing, perhaps FDR is in one of these. I should also note, it looks like the numbering restarted at some point in the late 30s or early 40s.

Comment: Sorry I miss understood how the strips are numbered, just ignore that part.

Comment: Hey Mark Rgers, Was Buck Rogers your grandpa? Why not ask one of your relatives and get back to us?